# how to restrict the input "shift+0" to "shift+9", but "shift" should accept (like "shift+A" or other)

Tags: jquery

I need to restrict input of special characters (like "/", "\") as well as "$" (shift+4), "#"(shift+3), but also need to allow capital characters like "A" (shift+a), etc.

Below code works, but I am not restrict "$" and all (from "shift+0" to "shift+9") as I'm allowing "shift", Give me some response how to do that,

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" id="txtboxToFilter" />
```

**Jquery**

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#txtboxToFilter").keydown(function (event) {
        // Allow: backspace, delete, tab, escape, and enter
        if (event.keyCode == 46 || event.keyCode == 8 || event.keyCode == 9 || event.keyCode == 27 || event.keyCode == 13 ||
        // Allow: Ctrl+A
        (event.keyCode == 65 && event.ctrlKey === true) ||
        // Allow: home, end, left, right
        (event.keyCode >= 35 && event.keyCode <= 39)) {
            // let it happen, don't do anything
            return;
        }
        else {
            // stop the keypress for special character "/", "\"
            if (event.keyCode >= 190) {
                event.preventDefault();
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: If you want to restrict the input of characters, you should only do this in the validation of the input. Trying to block key presses will fail, because there are a lot of different keyboard layouts (e.g. my # is alt-3). And most browsers support drag'n'drop for text inputs and copy-paste can not be prevented this easily. You could check the text fields content in the keyup callback, if you want to strip some characters out.

Comment: could you please come up with some code/link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment, if you want to prevent the use of specific characters, you should attack the problem on the character level, and not try to restrict the use of specific keys. I would do something like [in this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZA54d/). I am using a [regular expression](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_obj_regexp.asp) to replace all occurrences of unwanted characters. Because interrupting the user when typing is a bit odd, I used `change()` which is triggered when the text field loses the focus.

```
$("#text").change(function() {
    $("#text").val($("#text").val().replace(/\\|\//g, ""));
});​
```